# Mockk "verify" takes up to 6 seconds when verifying method with 3 or more parameters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, mockk, mockk-verify

I use mockk (versions 1.12.0 and 1.12.3) in `@SpringBootTest` in order to create a spy of some service and verify later that the service's method was (or was not) called. This looks like this:

```kotlin
@SpringBootTest
class MyTests {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var someBean: SomeBean

    @TestConfiguration
    class Config {
        @Bean
        @Primary
        fun someBeanSpy(someBean: SomeBean) = spyk(someBean)
    }

    @BeforeEach
    internal fun setUp() {
        clearAllMocks()
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("data")
    fun `some test`(s: String) {
        // prepare data and call controller
        verify(exactly = 0) { someBean.foo(any(), any(), any()) } // <- execution of this verify lasts about 6 seconds
        // other verify statements last about 200ms
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun data(): Stream<Arguments> = Stream.of(Arguments.of("abc"), Arguments.of("cde"))
    }
}
```

However, the execution of `verify` method on spy's methods with 3 or more parameters take too long time. Why may I have such behavior?

The same works fine with Mockito, but I don't want to use it with Kotlin because than I can't use just regular `Mockito#any` with non-nullable types.

Also, when I reduced the `SomeBean#foo` method's number of parameters from 3 to 2, `verify` executed just as normal, about 200ms.

Comment: First verify block may take time to construct Mockk internal objects. If your bean is never used, it might be faster to use `verify(exactly = 0) { someBean wasNot Called }`.

Comment: Suggestion: IntegrationTests are not made to verify behavior. They are used to verify configuration and dependency connections. You should slice parts down to a UnitTest and use mocks there. IntTest should just cover things like write/read from DB and assert result but not verify what was called. Just result matters.

Comment: @ocos I though about first block too, but it takes long time even if it is not a first block, e.g. third or second, but previous blocks run okay. I also tried `wasNot Called`, but it seems it doesn't work for spies.

Comment: @LenglBoy I agree with you, but for now I am at least just interested, what is the cause of the `verify` being executed so long.

Comment: `wasNot Called` works also for spies. We don't have full code here but if you use any method of `someBean`, `wasNot Called` verification will be failed. That bean should be Jack's Beanstalk.